# youtubedl stuck on 'downloading webpage' in python music bot

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I have everything setup, and everything installed properly. When I try to run the bot with !play command, the traceback is just on downloading web page. no errors at all. I'm suspecting it might be an error with the source, but I am not sure.

```
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
          if ctx.author.voice:
            await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
          else:
            await ctx.send("You're not connected to a voice channel.")
            raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
          ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnected_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info["formats"][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please take your question offline for now and take the [tour] and read [ask]. After that, rework it to include a [mcve] and a proper description of your observations, like e.g. the traceback you were referring to. BTW: When posting code, make sure to indent it consistently as well!

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit.

You will need the `YoutubeSearch` module

`pip install youtube-search`

```py
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch

@client.command()
async def play(ctx,*, song):
    voice_state = ctx.member.voice
    
    if voice_state == None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")
        return

    if voice_state != None:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    results = YoutubeSearch(song, max_results=1).to_dict()
    print(results)
    song_name = results[0]['title']
    url_suffix = results[0]['url_suffix']
    url = "https://youtube.com"+url_suffix

    playinge = discord.Embed(
        title = "Now Playing",
        description = f"[{song_name}]({url})",
        color = discord.Colour.green()
    )
    
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']

    vc = ctx.voice_client
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL))

    await ctx.send(embed=playinge)
```

Try this.

Comment: hey, thank you for this. It's not stuck anymore but the error now is "play() takes one positional argument while 2 were given. This is after running the !play command.